# Sql query to json result

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have these tables

```
destination (id integer, name text)
activity (id integer, name text, destination_id integer)
activity_duration (value numeric, unit text, label text,  activity_id integer)
activity_duration_price(amount numeric, currency_id integer, activity_duration_id integer)
```

Each destination has 1 or more activities, each activity has 1 or more duration and each duration has 1 price.

here is my query

```
select 
  d.id destination_id, 
  d.name destination_name, 
  count(a.id) as nb_activity, 
  string_agg('{"id":'||a.id||',"name":"'||a.name||'","pictures":"'||a.pictures||'","meta":{"price":'||amount||',"label":"'||label||'"}}',',') activities 
from destination d 
  left join activity a on (a.destination_id = d.id) 
  left join activity_duration ad on (activity_id = a.id) 
  left join activity_duration_price adp on (adp.activity_duration_id = ad.id) 
where d.id = any (array[142]) group by d.id, d.name order by nb_activity desc
```

and this is the result for the string_agg

```
    [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "visit tokyo",
    "meta": {
        "price": 210,
        "label": "Adult"
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "visit tokyo",
    "pictures": "{}",
    "meta": {
        "price": 170,
        "label": "Children"
    }
}]
```

As you can see, the meta information is there twice for the same item.

I want my result for the string_agg to be like this

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "visit tokyo",
    "meta": [{
            "price": 210,
            "label": "Adult"
        },
        {
            "price": 170,
            "label": "Children"
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: You have field in the query like `amount` and `label` which you did not mentioned in your tables.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) - to create array of rows

[array_to_json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) - to create JSON array

Then cast the JSON array to text.

```
SELECT
  d.id destination_id,
  d.name destination_name,
  count(a.id) AS nb_activity,
  string_agg('{"id":'||a.id||',"name":"'||a.name||'","pictures":"'||a.pictures||'","meta":'||
             (
               SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t))::TEXT --cast to TEXT to concatenate to the string
               FROM
               (
                 SELECT
                   adp.amount,
                   ad.label
                 FROM activity a2
                   LEFT JOIN activity_duration ad ON (ad.activity_id = a2.id)
                   LEFT JOIN activity_duration_price adp ON (adp.activity_duration_id = ad.id)
               ) AS t
             )
             ||'}'
  ,','
  ) AS activities
FROM destination d
  LEFT JOIN activity a ON (a.destination_id = d.id)
WHERE d.id = ANY (ARRAY[142]) GROUP BY d.id, d.name ORDER BY nb_activity DESC
```

Comment: wow! that's perfect! Thanks. The array_to_json function is awesome !